# SharePoint SitePages WebPart Updates

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am currently trying to create a translation tool for SharePoint SitePages, but there are some fields I just cannot manage to currently update.
Original page is in German, target is English.
For that, I use PnP.PowerShell to get the page, then go over the controls to update the text.
Sadly, even if I manage to get and update the Text of "Hero" and "Text" types, I currently don't see how I can get the other text contents of the WebParts (shown title of text captions).

Would anyone please have some info on how I can get there, or how I could have handled the issue in an easier manner?

Thanks

[image: Sample fail]

Code currently looks a bit like that:

```
$newPage = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "$targetlanguage/$pageTitle"

$textControls = $newPage.Controls | ? {$_.Type.name -eq "PageText"}
$pageWebParts = $newPage.Controls | ? {$_.Type.Name -eq "PageWebPart"}
Write-Host "Translating content..." -NoNewline

foreach ($textControl in $textControls){
    if (($textControl.Text -ne $null) -and ($textControl.Text -ne "")) {
        $translatedControlText = Start-Translation -text $textControl.Text -language $targetLanguage
        Set-PnPPageTextPart -Page $newPage -InstanceId $textControl.InstanceId -Text "$($translatedControlText)"
    }
}
foreach ($WebComponent in $pageWebParts) {
    $properties = $WebComponent.PropertiesJson | ConvertFrom-Json
    foreach ($content in $properties.content) {
        if (($content.description -ne $null) -and ($content.description.getType().name -eq "String") -and ($content.description -ne "")) {
            $content.description = Start-Translation -text $content.description -language $targetLanguage
        }
        if (($content.featureText -ne $null) -and ($content.featureText.getType().name -eq "String") -and ($content.featureText -ne "")) {
            $content.featureText = Start-Translation -text $content.featureText -language $targetLanguage
        }
    }
    if (($properties.altText -ne $null) -and ($properties.altText.getType().name -eq "String") -and ($properties.altText -ne "")) {
        $properties.altText = Start-Translation -text $properties.altText -language $targetLanguage
    }
    if (($properties.overlayText -ne $null) -and ($properties.overlayText.getType().name -eq "String") -and ($properties.overlayText -ne "")) {
        $properties.overlayText = Start-Translation -text $properties.overlayText -language $targetLanguage
    }
    Set-PnPPageWebPart -Page "$targetlanguage/$pageTitle" -Identity $WebComponent.InstanceId -PropertiesJson ($properties | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 90)
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with modern Sharepoint automation, but wouldn't this be better served as a browser extension?

Comment: Sadly, not for my current use case and the requirements I got :(